# Задача на скобочки

Tags: c++

Задача:
Некоторые скобочные структуры правильные, другие - неправильные. Ваша задача: определить, правильная ли скобочная структура.

Вход: Слово в алфавите из двух круглых скобочек ( и ), [, ], {, }. Длина слова меньше 40001.

Выход: Либо 'NO', либо 'YES' без кавычек.

Вот текст моей программы, но она не проходит все тесты. Не пойму, где ошибка.  И какие тесты она не проходит (не смог таких придумать).

```
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::stack < char > st;
    std::stack < char > st1;
    std::stack < char > st2;

    bool f = true, g = true, k = true;
    int index = 0;

    while (index < s.length() && f && g && k)
    {
        if (s[index] == ')')
        {
            f = (!st.empty());
            if (f)
                st.pop();
        }
        else
        if (s[index] == ']')
        {
            g = (!st1.empty());
            if (g)
                st1.pop();
        }
        else
        if (s[index] == '}')
        {
            k = (!st2.empty());
            if (k)
                st2.pop();
        }
        else
        if (s[index] == '(')
        {
            st.push(s[index]);
        }
        else
        if (s[index] == '[')
        {
            st1.push(s[index]);
        }
        else
        if (s[index] == '{')
        {
            st2.push(s[index]);
        }

        index++;
    }
    std::cout << (((k && f && g && st.empty() && st1.empty() && st2.empty()) ? "YES" : "NO")) << std::endl;

}
```

Прошу помощи.

**Обновление**

Программа работает, но на каких-то тестах она работает неправильно (при загрузке в систему проходят не все тесты). Какие там тесты, мне не известно. И я не могу выяснить, при каких условиях она ошибается, прошу помочь именно в этом.

Просто хочу научиться работать со стеком. Не подумал о Вашем примере. Попробовал реализовать заново с помощью трех стеков, Ваш пример теперь работает правильно, но снова не проходит все тесты в системе. Код изменил в ответе. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @doomsday, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Вы говорите, что программа не проходит, а затем пишите, что не знаете как тестировать. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я и не прошу завершать за меня. Программа работает, но на каких-то тестах она работает неправильно (при загрузке в систему проходят не все тесты). Какие там тесты, мне не известно. И я не могу выяснить, при каких условиях она ошибается, прошу помочь именно в этом.

Comment: @doomsday, с подсчетом вроде никаких проблем, но вопрос о том, что такое "правильная структура" остается. К примеру, является ли такая структура {(([)}]) правильной? Важен ли порядок вложения или только количество скобок? Все таки слово "структура" подразумевают какую-то организацию. 

И еще, есть ли какие-нибудь ограничения на время и память для приложения?

Comment: @Alex Krass, и об этом я не подумал. Действительно, получается, что { ( ( [ ) } ] ) является не правильной. А правильной ({()[]}),т.е порядок все-таки важен. Ограничение времени:1 с, Ограничение памяти:64 M.

Comment: @Alex Krass, я понял Вашу идею. Только вот код не компилируется, и я не могу поправить.

Comment: Это очень крутая задача, у нас в 57ой школе она в 10м классе была. Решение ее совсем не тривиально.

Comment: @doomsday, перенес комментарии в ответ, тут место кончается для обсуждения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Я не вижу, чтобы у вас использовался флаг k в проверке while.
2. Как вы думаете, что произойдет при входе "[{))" в вашу программу и является ли это правильным.
3. Не указаны критерии правильности скобочных структур, к примеру, могут ли они быть пересекающимися.

По хорошему, вам нужно считать количество каждого вида скобок, без всяких стеков и прочих наворотов: int round=0, rect=0, figure=0;

Если опустилось ниже 0 во время прохождения, значит ошибка в структуре скобок и выполнить break, если по окончанию строки не все стали, снова равны нулю, тоже ошибка.

**UPDATE 1 (неверный)**

Тогда можно ограничиться одним стеком и организовать проверку только выталкиваемого из стека значения pop(), чтобы оно содержало аналогичную открывающую скобку. Ясли не ошибаюсь, этого достаточно:

```
if (s[index] == ')') f = (!st.empty() && st.pop()=='(');
if (s[index] == ']') g = (!st.empty() && st.pop()=='[');
if (s[index] == '}') k = (!st.empty() && st.pop()=='{');
if (s[index]=='['||s[index]=='{'||s[index]=='(') st.push(s[index]);
```

Соответственно проверка флагов в цикле и при выводе ответа (+ на пустоту стека) остается.

**UPDATE 2 (исправленный)**

[[@doomsday](/users/24309/doomsday)](/users/24309/doomsday), прошу прощения, я не часто имею дело с С++, для возврата значения из стека надо использовать вместо pop() функция top(). То есть по идее следующий код должен решать поставленную задачу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str;
    stack<char> st;
    int index = 0;
    bool f = true, g = true, k = true;

    cin >> str;

    while (index < str.length() && f && g && k)
    {
        char chr = str[index];
        if (chr == '[' || chr == '{' || chr == '(') st.push(chr);
        if (chr == ')') f = (!st.empty() && st.top() == '(');
        if (chr == ']') g = (!st.empty() && st.top() == '[');
        if (chr == '}') k = (!st.empty() && st.top() == '{');
        index++;
    }

    cout << (k && f && g && st.empty() ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, отличный вариант.

Comment: Да, все хорошо работает. Спасибо огромное. А еще не подскажите, как сделать, чтобы она пропускала пробелы? Т.к. если между скобками пробел, то она работает неправильно.

Comment: @doomsday, так работает оператор считывания cin >> str, он считывает только слово в переменные, пробел для него разделитель. То есть можно писать так:

    cin >> a >> b >> c; // ввод с консоли: 10 20 30

Чтобы иметь возможность считывать строку с пробелами, надо использовать другие функции Input/Output. Например, какой-нибудь cin.getline() или что-то еще посмотреть.

Comment: не получается считать по-другому..

Comment: Все разобрался, списаибо

Comment: @Alex Krass: +1, но в принципе можно обойтись без флагов: http://ideone.com/j6Dcnc

Comment: Я что-то не вижу, где `index` увеличивается. Вот похожий алгоритм, который поддерживает Юникодные скобки: http://ideone.com/LDzXea

Comment: @jfs: Отдельный токенайзер [избавил бы](http://ideone.com/s9GVmA) от дорогого сравнения строк. И код получается чище. Ваш код `O(длина входящей строки * количество скобок)`.

Comment: @VladD: верно. [Код](http://ideone.com/LDzXea) содержит комментарий, что он `O(n*k)`, и его можно считать линейным, только если `k` (количество скобок) это константа. Я не читаю Си-шарп, но код с токеназейром выглядит приятно (кратко и понятно). Правильно ли я понимаю, что он не поддерживает многобайтовые скобочки? В общем случае мне нравится идея токенайзера, она позволяет упростить во многих случаях задачу по разборке ввода и делает код более читабельным. Без бенчмарка, я бы не стал утверждать "дорогое" в данном случае сравнение или нет.

Comment: @jfs: А, и правда. Код действительно не поддерживал многосимвольные скобки (многобайтные для C# не проблема, т. к. в нём `char` — это многобайтный Unicode char). Вот [этот вариант](http://ideone.com/wNyQle) лучше, но всё ещё не поддерживает из-за крайне простого токенизатора (который определяет тип токена по символу). Более сложный токенизатор долженпо идее строить [префиксное дерево](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) (или `O(n*k) не избежать).

Comment: @jfs, да, index не увеличивается. Писал без компилятора и проверки, банально не доглядел.

@VladD, а что это за конструкция в 28-й строке по первой вашей ссылке на http://ideone.com/j6Dcnc: for (char c : s) { ... }? Неужели в С++ появился for-in?

Comment: @Alex Krass: Уже давно, с C++11.

Comment: @jfs: Вот вариант с [многосимвольными скобками](http://ideone.com/WVLkqW) (подправил токенайзер, производительность `O(n*k)`). На Питоне должно быть ещё проще, т. к. функциональщина там пишется легче.

Comment: @Alex Krass: в c++17 возможно будет писать: [`for (item : sequence) {...}`, что соответствует `for (auto&& item: sequence)` в с++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: @VladD: [вариант c  многосимвольными скобками](http://ideone.com/WVLkqW) по сути использует тот же [алгоритм, который я предложил для многобайтовых скобок](http://ideone.com/LDzXea) -- только отдельный токенайзер делает код более ясным и понятным.

Comment: @jfs: Так и есть, я не нашёл в C# radix tree «из коробки».

Answer (score 4):

Не помню решения этой задачи без рекурсии. Через рекурсию решается более-менее просто, вот так:

```
class Braces
{
public:
    enum class br_type 
    {
        _br_head,
        _br_round,
        _br_square,
        _br_figure
    };

    Braces(br_type type, char* line) : _type(type)
    {
        int runner = 0;
        while(line[runner] == '(' || line[runner] == '[' or line[runner] == '{')
        {
            if (line[runner] == '(')
                _sub_braces.push_back(Braces(br_type::_br_round, &line[runner + 1]));
            else if (line[runner] == '[')
                _sub_braces.push_back(Braces(br_type::_br_square, &line[runner + 1]));   
            else if (line[runner] == '{')
                _sub_braces.push_back(Braces(br_type::_br_figure, &line[runner + 1]));    
            runner += _sub_braces.back().size();
        }
        if (runner == strlen(line) && _type == br_type::_br_head)
            return;
        if (line[runner] == ')' && _type != br_type::_br_round)
            throw std::exception("NO");
        if (line[runner] == ']' && _type != br_type::_br_square)
            throw std::exception("NO");
        if (line[runner] == '}' && _type != br_type::_br_figure)
            throw std::exception("NO");     
    }
    int size() { return 2 + sum_sizes(_sub_braces); }
    int sum_sizes(vector<Braces>& braces) 
    {    
        int res = 0;
        for (auto& br : braces)
        {
            res += br.size();
        }
        return res; 
    }
    br_type _type;
    vector<Braces> _sub_braces;
};
```

Код написал тут, т.е. не проверял, но идея рекурсии, думаю, ясна. Если внешний объект (с типом `_br_head`, которому передается вся строка) создатся без exception, то надо выводить ОК, иначе сообщение exception-а. Сделав nasty эксепшны, можно даже указать, на какой именно вложенности получена ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

#define TEST    1
#define VERBOSE 1

#if TEST
const char * testInput[] = {
    "[ ]",
    "{ }",
    "( )",
    "< >",
    "rth(zxc<[{e r}wer]fdg>zxc)hj",
    "il.)rge{ }",
    "sdl  fkv[flv,]",
    "fv[dsfnv>jn(bk) l",
    "(rg er>erg",
    "<rge{sd}gk"
};
#endif

enum {
    OpeningBrace   = 0,
    ClosingBrace   = 1,
    BracePair      = 2
};

const char braces[][BracePair] = {
    { '{', '}' },
    { '[', ']' },
    { '(', ')' },
    { '<', '>' }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::stack<int> braceIndeces;
    std::string input;
    bool error = false;

#if TEST
  #if VERBOSE
    std::cout << "Running tests..."
              << std::endl << std::endl;
  #endif
    for (size_t testInputIdx = 0;
                testInputIdx < sizeof(testInput) / sizeof(testInput[0]);
                ++testInputIdx) {
        input = testInput[testInputIdx];
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
#else
  #if VERBOSE
    std::cout << "Enter char sequence with braces..."
              << std::endl << std::endl;
  #endif
    std::cin >> input;
#endif

        size_t inputIdx = 0;
        std::string::iterator itr = input.begin();
        for (; itr != input.end(); ++itr, ++inputIdx) {
            char ch = *itr;

            size_t currentBracesIdx = braceIndeces.empty()
                                    ? (size_t)-1
                                    : braceIndeces.top();

            for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(braces) / sizeof(braces[0]); ++i) {
                if (ch == braces[i][OpeningBrace]) {
                    braceIndeces.push(i);
                    break;
                }
                else if (ch == braces[i][ClosingBrace]) {
                    if (currentBracesIdx == i)
                        braceIndeces.pop();
                    else { // error
                        error = true;
                        if (currentBracesIdx == (size_t)-1) {
#if VERBOSE
                            std::cout << "Error: unexpected brace char '"
                                      << ch << "' at "
                                      << inputIdx
                                      << ", braces not opened"
                                      << std::endl << std::endl;
#else
                            std::cout << "NO" << std::endl << std::endl;
#endif
                        }
                        else {
#if VERBOSE
                            std::cout << "Error: unexpected brace char '"
                                      << ch
                                      << "' at " << inputIdx
                                      << ", should be '"
                                      << braces[currentBracesIdx][ClosingBrace]
                                      << "'"
                                      << std::endl << std::endl;
#else
                            std::cout << "NO" << std::endl << std::endl;
#endif
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                // else tested char is not a brace char
            }
            if (error)
                break;

        }

        if (error)
            error = false;
        else {
            if (!braceIndeces.empty()) {
#if VERBOSE
                std::cout << "Error: unclosed braces, '"
                          << braces[braceIndeces.top()][ClosingBrace]
                          << "' expected at the end"
                          << std::endl << std::endl;
                braceIndeces = std::stack<int>();
#else
                std::cout << "NO" << std::endl << std::endl;
#endif
            }
            else
                std::cout << "YES" << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
#if TEST
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}
```